# Count object with same attributevalues in list of objects with GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I got a class:

```
public class result
{
    public int A;
    public int B;
    public int C;
}
```

I make a list of it:

```
public static List<result> results = new List<result>();
```

I then fill that list with random data
Somthing like 10,000,000 enteries, where a, b and c will have a value of 0 to 24.

I would like to show in my console what combo has been found and how many
in SQL it would be somthing like:

```
SELECT A, B, C, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM results
GROUP BY A, B, C
```

And i have tried so many things, i think i can write a book about it.
some of the stuff i tried:

```
var query1 = results.GroupBy(x => new { x.A, x.B, x.C }).Select(group => new { Value = group.Key, Count = group.Count() });

var query2 = from r in results group r by new { r.A, r.B, r.C } into rGroup select rGroup;

var query3 = results.GroupBy(x => new { x.A, x.B, x.C })  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Count());

var query4 = from r in results
                          group r by new { r.A, r.B, r.C } into rGroup
                          select new { key = rGroup.Key, cnt = rGroup.Count() };
```

But nothing seems to work.
I would like to get back a list with the a,b,c values and a count of how many have been found.

Yet im unable to get it working, i tried hours of googleing and tried everything, at this point i am completly lost.

Comment: Are you trying to get a count of how many distinct combinations there are?  Meaning if you have 3 items in your list `{ [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [4,5,6] }` you would get a count of 2 back?

Comment: I can not understasnd that example query. What is group by doing there? Could you give us a example table with example output? Something a bit smaler then 10k?

Comment: yes maccettura, thats what i would like to see

Comment: Example output : https://i.imgur.com/wu7j37D.png

Comment: Those queries that don't work: what do they do instead of working?

Comment: @phoog, they give me back a list of all combos and a count, the issues is that the count is always 1 and the list that i get back is still filled with dublicates

Comment: 1: Don't put images in instead of text; 2: How come your output only has 3 columns when your SQL generates 4?; 3: `query1` & `query4` matches your SQL.

Comment: Maybe it's time for a complete runnable example that produces the incorrect output along with a sample of the expected output.

Comment: If `A:1, B:2, C:3` would that be considered the same as `A:3, B:2, C:1`?  And if it is considered the same, do you _have_ to have individual properties or could you use a collection of int in your class?

Comment: Also, that example output makes no sense because there is a duplicate in the list: `[2,0,0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the GroupBy part right - you just need to select the groups into another object that has the A, B and C values of the group, along with the count of the group:

```
results.GroupBy(x => new { x.A, x.B, x.C })
    .Select(g => new { g.Key.A, g.Key.B, g.Key.C, Count = g.Count()})
```

Comment: I'm curious to know why this answer was downvoted. It looks like exactly what the OP wanted.

Comment: I think the problem is no one knew what the OP wanted because it was never made clear.  It was a very vague and unclear question

Comment: @ImtehQ your example output has duplicates though. Like I said. Super unclear.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness sake a full example.

Same solutions as nlawalker though, producing a dict.

```
public class result
{
    public int A;
    public int B;
    public int C;

    public result(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random r = new Random(23);

    var data = new List<result>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        data.Add(new result(r.Next(1, 3), r.Next(1, 3), r.Next(1, 3)));

    var dic = data
        .GroupBy(k => new { k.A, k.B, k.C })
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

    foreach (var kvp in dic)
        Console.WriteLine($"({kvp.Key.A},{kvp.Key.B},{kvp.Key.C}) : {kvp.Value}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
(2,2,2) : 13
(1,2,2) : 11
(2,1,1) : 9
(1,1,1) : 16
(1,2,1) : 14
(1,1,2) : 15
(2,1,2) : 7
(2,2,1) : 15
```

Comment: That is indeed what nlawalker posted, nice way of stealing the up votes :/

Comment: @ImtehQ  I am not steeling, you can upvote both. or just him or just me. When I was programming/testing my solution he answered and when I posted he had already his in. Mine has the benefit of a full fledged sample.  I spent about a quarter hour of  my free spare time to give you an answer and did not like to ditch my work nor time. I even upvoted his answer jfye.